# Decode a JWT token automatically in Charles Proxy

Tags: base64, jwt, remote-debugging, charles-proxy

I've been using Charles to debug the communication between a mobile app and an API.

We are now changing both the client (app) and the server to use JSON Web Tokens ([JWT](https://jwt.io/introduction/)).

Is there a way to configure Charles so that the JWT is decoded when browsing the requests ?

---

Basically, the request (from mobile app to server) will consist of a single header (Authorization) containing the JWT, and when I click on that request in Charles, I'd like to see:
 - the original token
 - the decoded header
 - the decoded payload

Looking at Charles' documentation, I found the following:
 - **Rewrite tool**: could replace the token with the decoded data, but it doesn't seem like functions (base64decode) are supported, only plain text or and regexp replacement.
 - **Map Remote tool**: seems like it could do the job, by calling a script on a server which takes in the original request as an argument, and returns the new request with the decoded data. The documentation describes a use for replacing specific sources (when browsing a website), so I'm having a hard time seeing how it could be applied to this case (client to API communication). Doesn't seem like it can pass the original request as an argument (just replaces it).

I know that I could always copy paste the token in a tool that decodes JWT, but that's a small step that I will be repeating a hundred/thousands of times, so I'd like to avoid it.

Or is there another way to debug HTTP requests between mobile and server that are encoded in JWT format ?

Comment: Searching for this exactly. Did you find anything? Thanks

Comment: I haven't unfortunately ...

Answer (score 1):

Since Charles Proxy doesn't support JWT Decode feature, you can try out [Proxyman](https://proxyman.io), which automatically decode JWT and display in a nice place.

[image: JWT Decode]

If you need to manipulate it, you can take a look at [JWT Decode Addon](https://docs.proxyman.io/scripting/addons) . The Scripting feature allows you to write JS code to achieve the same result.

Disclaimer: I'm a creator of Proxyman. Hope this answer could help you.